# lodash: union array of objects

Tags: arrays, lodash, union

I'd like to union an array of object as below:

```
[{end: 1, start: 10},
 {end: 11, start: 20},
 {end: 21, start: 29}]
```

If `array[i].start == array[i+1].end + 1`, union them, for example

before:

```
[{end: 1, start: 10},
{end: 11, start: 20}]
```

after:

```
{end: 1, start: 20}
```

Not be familiar with lodash, is there a simple method can implement it?

Comment: What will be your final output?

Comment: As above mentioned, after union, the array should be {end:1, start:29}

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
    var obj = [{end: 1, start: 10},{end: 11, start: 20},{end: 21, start: 29}]
    var max = { start: _.maxBy( obj, "start" ).start }
    var min = { end: _.minBy( obj, "end" ).end }

    _.extend(max,min)

   //{start: 29, end: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use `lodash` for this. with **ES6** it would be just one [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const data = [{ end: 1, start: 10 }, { end: 11, start: 20 } ] 

const result = data.reduce((r,c,i) => {
  r.end = c.end < r.end || i == 0 ? c.end : r.end
  r.start = c.start > r.start ? c.start : r.start
  return r
}, { end: 0, start: 0 })

console.log(result)
```

With lodash you could do something like this:

```js
const data = [{ end: 1, start: 10 }, { end: 11, start: 20 }] 

const r = _.merge(_.minBy(data, 'end'), _.pick(_.maxBy(data,'start'), 'start'))

console.log(r)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The idea is to get the max and min and then [merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#merge) the objects. The trick however is to only [pick](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#pick) the `start` property in the merge so you do not overwrite the `end`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your  reply.
I will try it.